# Weird behaviour of TextInput on android react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, textinput

I have a signup form where I want to clear the textinput when user focuses it and keyboard pops up.

This behaviour works just fine on iOS , however on android , first thing is clearTextOnFocus doesn't work, secondly I am not able to type anything into address text input, I wonder whats wrong here, since this works just perfect on iOS.

```
export default class SignupScreen extends Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    title: strings.signup,
    headerTintColor:'black'
};
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loading:true,loginText:strings.username,pwdText:strings.password,nameText:strings.name,phoneNoText:strings.phone,addressText:strings.address,lineIdText:strings.line,loading:false };



}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (


        <ImageBackground
            source={require('./images/marble.jpg')}
            style={styles.backgroundImage}>

            <KeyboardAwareScrollView>

                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Spinner visible={this.state.loading} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />

                    <Image style = {styles.logoFit} resizeMode="contain"  source={require('./images/Logo1.png')}/>

                    <View>
                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.loginText }
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue1) => this.setState({loginText:textInputValue1})} keyboardType='email-address' ></TextInput>

                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.pwdText}
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue2) => this.setState({pwdText:textInputValue2})}></TextInput>

                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.phoneNoText}
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue) => this.setState({phoneNoText:textInputValue})}></TextInput>

                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.nameText}
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue) => this.setState({nameText:textInputValue})}></TextInput>

                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.addressText}
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue) => this.setState({adressText:textInputValue})}></TextInput>

                        <TextInput clearTextOnFocus={true} style={styles.textInput} value={this.state.lineIdText}
                                   onChangeText={(textInputValue) => this.setState({lineIdText:textInputValue})}></TextInput>


                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonSection}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {this.onSignup}>
                            <View style = { styles.donebutton}>
                                <Text style = {{color: 'white'}}>{strings.signup}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
     </ImageBackground>


    );
}
}
```

Any help in this direction will be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you set `value` property of `TextInput`. If `value` is set, it will override everything you try to write in it. You should use `defaultValue` property instead.

**UPDATE**
Clearing text was known issue, but it's marked as fixed. If you still having problem with it, try https://github.com/nikolaiwarner/react-native-text-input-reset

Comment: It's strange, it shouldn't.. but, did you tried this?

Comment: to add on @pavle answer `clearTextOnFocus` is iOS only property, does not work on Android for now(v0.56.0). Check the RN docs.